# LINQ Select Row with Max date per group

Tags: linq

I want to return all the values from my "Categories" table and join that to my "CategorySelections" table to display all the categories and whether the specified user selected them or not.
A complication (which I don't know how to deal with in LINQ) is that the user could have changed his selection/deselection of a particular category over time...each change would have logged in the "CategorySelections" table with a date stamp.
I am after the last selection status.

The following SQL query does what I want:

```
     SELECT cs.UserId, c.CategoryId, m.MaxDate, cs.IsSelected
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[Categories] c
  LEFT JOIN [myDB].[dbo].[CategorySelections] cs
  ON c.CategoryID = cs.CategoryID AND cs.UserID = 7
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT UserId, CategoryId, Max(CreatedOn) as MaxDate
    FROM [myDB].[dbo].[CategorySelections]
    GROUP BY UserId, CategoryId
  ) m
  ON cs.UserID = m.UserID AND cs.CategoryID = m.CategoryID AND cs.CreatedOn = m.MaxDate
  ORDER BY cs.CategoryI
```

I need some help getting this done in LINQ.
Below is my attempt, which returns all the selections instead of just the last per category.

```
var query = from c in db.Category
join cs in db.CategorySelection.Where(x => x.UserID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
on c.CategoryID equals cs.CategoryID into JoinedCategory
from cs in JoinedCategory.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new Selection() { CategoryID = c.CategoryID, CategoryName = c.CategoryName       ,IsSelected = cs != null ? cs.IsSelected : false }
```

I am working in MVC; the "new Selection()" refers to my Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add WHERE statement:

```
where cs.CreatedOn == CategorySelections.Where(t => t.CategoryId == cs.CategoryId).Max(r => r.CreatedOn)
```

Comment: I assume I add that before the "select". It says "the name CategorySelections" does not exist in the current context. I then change it to "cs".But then it says "does not contain a definition for Max"

Comment: I think you probably meant "JoindedCategory" instead of "CategorySelection"? Doing that produces no errors but also returns no result.

Comment: I meant `db.CategorySelection`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had to bring in a condition || null since the user might not have made any selections yet